# google place search location biasing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using Google Places search and I want "Location Biasing" on GCC countries (UAE, Saudi Arabia, Oman, Kuwait & Bahrain).

I want to achieve the below 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete#location_biasing

I want to provide Google Places search on a textbox where user can only see results from these countries UAE, Saudi Arabia, Oman, Kuwait & Bahrain?

Thanks,

---

I can "Location Bias" on one country using "componentRestrictions" argument as shown in the below code snippet

```
var mapOptions = {
          //bounds : defaultBounds,  
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.2644444, 55.31166669999993),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');        
        var InputOptions = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            **componentRestrictions: { country: 'AE' } // I want multiple counteries here**
        };                
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, InputOptions);
```

But I want Location Biasing on multiple counteries that i mention above.

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2017 you can now create filter for multiple countries in Place autocomplete.

> You can now restrict Autocomplete predictions to only surface from multiple countries. You can do this by specifying up to 5 countries in the componentRestrictions field of the AutocompleteOptions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ComponentRestrictions

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do?

If I get you right, you just want to geocode one of these countries (UAE,Saudi Arabia, Oman, Kuwait & Bahrain)?

```
  function geocodeAddress() {
    var address = "Oman";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        position: results[0].geometry.location // gives you the location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Error: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: i have modified the question details

Comment: sorry... i still don't get it :( do you want to display all place-names of the countries UAE, Saudi Arabia, Oman, Kuwait and Bahrain in a dropdown menu?

Comment: there is a thing called "Location Biasing" in google places API. I want Location Biading for  the countries (UAE, Saudi Arabia, Oman, Kuwait and Bahrain) in textbox where i am providing lookup search for some region from the above counteries.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible (at the moment). Restricting results to *one* country was only added as feature some weeks ago. Your best option is to restrict the results by your map bounds as shown in this example from the [Places Library website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631)); 

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Find the bounds that fit best to your desired region.